# How to work with configuration in Spring MVC web application?

Tags: spring, configuration

I am new in Spring and I'm working on my first Spring MVC web application.

I use a class that holds setting of my application.

```
public class Configuration {

    @Value("${chart.width}")
    private int chartWidth;
    @Value("${chart.height}")
    private int chartHeight;

    public int getChartWidth() {
        return chartWidth;
    }

    public void setChartWidth(int chartWidth) {
        this.chartWidth = chartWidth;
    }

    public int getChartHeight() {
        return chartHeight;
    }

    public void setChartHeight(int chartHeight) {
        this.chartHeight = chartHeight;
    }
}
```

All setting are loaded from one .properties file.

In applicationContext.xml I create a bean from this class:

```
<bean id="configuration" class="utils.Configuration" />
```

Next I have one abstract class and all my controlers are extended from this class:

```
public class AController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("configuration")
    private Configuration configuration;

    public Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    public void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

Now I can to ask for Configuration object and get required setting.

**Question:** is there some better method how to work with configuration in Spring MVC web application? I would like to work with configuration in Controllers, DAO and Service objects and in view (JSP).

Comment: So, inject the confirguration bean into your service and DAO objects. What's the problem?

Comment: If you add autowired annotation on the field itself, there is no need for the getter and setter methods. Because in this case Spring will bind the field using reflection, not calling the setter.

Comment: @JBNizet - there is no problem, it works as I explained but I'm not only sure this is the best method. It makes me wonder if is there some more simple method (e.g. semiautomatic).

Comment: That already looks quite automatic to me. You could also directly inject chartWidth or chartHeight or both in any other bean, just like you did with Configuration.